# Laravel Jobs - dynamic queues, delay between jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, jobs, job-scheduling

I have dilemma with implementation for Laravel Jobs - queues.
I need make queue for shops entities - **orders** and **products** synchronization to other api (limited requests for minute). But I need that shops don't influence each other.

E.g. I have shop that need synchronize 1000 products. But in same time there is other shop with product that needed to be synchronized too.

1. I need **set delay for synchronization because of limited API req/min (this API have limitation by shop so 2 shops can process at once)**. How can I set some delay between job for first shop from example to process this 1000 products.
   E.g. API is limited 10req/1min (10req/60s). How can I set delay 6s between each job?
2. I need **avoid that second shop must wait while first shop will process** this 1000 products.

What I try:

*for delay:* `sleep([6s])` in Laravel Job handle (not working) because when I get 3 products jobs at same time, I cannot send him with this delay between each other. I try set `delay([6s])` for Laravel Job, but same result too.

*for avoid waiting:* I tought about dynamic creation queues (for each shop separated) but I don't know if Laravel Jobs makes smoething like this possible.

Any idea how implement this situation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using carbon, Eg:

```
$dateTime = "2022-08-12 12:00:00";
$carbonDate = Carbon::parse($date);
JobsPublishArticle::dispatch()->delay($dateTime);
```

Or

```
$dateTime = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10); // you can use minutes, hours, etc too.
JobsPublishArticle::dispatch()->delay($dateTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. It won't work. When I get 3 entities one after other in a few ms, then Carbon::now() will be almost the same for this entities so it won't have any effect.